# Is it possible to pull a value from a closed excel workbook, whose name is chosen based on a value in the current worksheet

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

Is it possible to pull a value from a closed excel workbook, whose name is chosen based on a value in the current worksheet?

For example, `='[Bracket (KYLE GRAHAM).xlsx]BRACKET'!$F25` is the cell that I want to locate, but instead of `KYLE GRAHAM`, I would like to use a cell from the current worksheet.

Comment: `Is it possible to pull a value from a closed excel workbook` - unfortunatelly, using only formulas - not. VBA can help you

Comment: Do you know of such a macro?  i haven't had much luck searching the internet

Comment: you can start from [here](http://spreadsheetpage.com/index.php/tip/a_vba_function_to_get_a_value_from_a_closed_file/) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13811398/refer-to-excel-workbook-by-path-based-on-cell-value-data?rq=1)

Comment: In this case, I don't need the desired cell to match one in my active worksheet, I just want it to pull from a file based on a value in the active worksheet.  Using'C:\Users\kgraham\Dropbox\[workbook" & Range("D1").Value & ".xlsx]TRASH'!A1.  My file is named TRASH.xlsx, so I have placed "TRASH" in cell D1, however I keep receiving a #REF! error.

Answer (score 0):

This code opens the workbook and captures a cells value then closes the workbook again without displaying the action:

```
Function WorkbookLookup(Path As String, SheetName As String, CellAddress As String)
'Hides action and warnings
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
'Saves the name of the current wb to return after action
InitialWB = ActiveWorkbook.Name
'opens the specified wb
Workbooks.Open Path
'captures the cell's value
WorkbookLookup = Sheets(SheetName).Range(CellAddress).Value
'closes the workbook
ActiveWorkbook.Close False
'activates the original wb
Workbooks(InitialWB).Activate
'turns on warnings and action display
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Function
```